# Real purchase on development build on iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ane

How can I make sure that my in app purchases really works?

I developed my app on AIR, as3 and for billing I use InAppPurchase ANE from Distriqts.

I did try everything in sandbox as it is described in apple site - everything works just fine.

When I try to test development build with real iTunes account I get purchase_failed event.

But when I submit my app to iTunes it was rejected because IAP didn't work. Is there a way to install current build on iPhone with distribution provision profile and make a real purchase (I have approved IAP for this app already)? Or how I can make sure that it properly set-up?

Comment: What was the exact reason for them rejecting your application?

Comment: @Michael it was my bad - It appears that if you use server-side receipt verification you must support on production fail-back mechanism to handle Sandbox purchases (this is how Apple does testing)

Comment: Ah no problems. Always painful getting things through review.

Comment: @Michael it is sooo true))